# SV constraints scope and randomization

Tags: constraints, system-verilog, verification

In a SystemVerilog UVM testbench, we're randomizing transaction objects, and for some specific tests, we create additional constraints. However those testcase constraints are only used by the randomization engine if you call the testcase `randomize()` method and not `obj.randomize()`. This is quite confusing.

I wonder why all constraints on the object are not used regardless of which randomize is called? Why do constraints have a scope?

For example:

```cpp
class trans;
   rand int addr;
 
   constraint addr_c;  // Method 1: constraint prototype

   function void post_randomize();
     $display("addr %d",addr);
   endfunction
endclass

//////////////////// Test case code /////////////////

// Method 1: extend constraint prototype addr_c external to test class.
// constraint trans::addr_c { addr > 0 && addr < 10; } 
// works but requires prototype, careful if trans is in another package

class my_test;
  trans trans1;
  
  // Method 2: Add constraint to the test
  constraint test_constraint_c { trans1.addr > 11 && trans1.addr < 20; }
  
  function new();
    trans1 = new;
    repeat (20) begin
      // This doesn't use test_constraint_c (why??)
      assert(trans1.randomize()) else $display("TEST", "Randomization Failed");
      // This uses test_constraint_c
      assert(randomize(trans1)) else $display("TEST", "Randomization Failed");
    end
  endfunction
endclass

module tb;
  my_test test1;
  initial test1 = new;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 classes which are unrelated to each other: `trans` and `my_test`.

The `trans` class does not know about the `test_constraint_c` constraint because the constraint is only part of the `my_test` class.  Thus, when you call the `randomize` function on the object (`trans1.randomize()`), it has no constraints to apply.

In the test, when you call the `randomize` method on the `trans1` variable, it will apply any active constraints in the `my_test` class, namely `test_constraint_c`.

An alternate approach is to extend the `trans` class with a new constraint block.